# How to open a netbook case after removing all screws?

Tags: netbook, case, maintenance, unmounting, screws

My Sony VAIO netbook case is closed, all I could remove so far is a dozen of screws, some covers, the battery and the hard disk.

Using a screwdriver I investigated the keyboard keys, the keyboard mask and the slit between the upper and lower case parts.

I found some pressure fitting points in the slit.

I could force one of the sides of the case to become free, but I couldn't free all sides of the case at once.

Is there any tip I should follow when opening such netbook case?

Comment: Did you follow some guide to unscrew everything? Some of them might be hidden or underneath some parts...

Comment: Second that. Also, search for a "maintenance manual". (Not the regular user manual, but the one for repair technicians).